# Parsing xml with python (find tags with specific text)

Tags: xml, python-3.x, csv, lxml, export-to-csv

I have been tasked with processing an xml file, to find specific elements and export them in a csv file..

I am specificly having trouble with some information that is keept in the same tags:

```
<name>text</name>
<value>value</value>
```

each name tag contains a different value and I only need some of them..
I have tried looping through the file with this code:

```
try:
        descr = member.find('.//name').text
        if descr == 'description':
            plugin.append(descr)
    except AttributeError:
        descr = 'Unknown'
        plugin.append(descr)
```

But it only returns 'Unknown'

My whole code is as such (not finished):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse('plugins.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

nessus_out = open('/home/rj/Documents/python/nessus_out.csv', 'w')

csvwriter = csv.writer(nessus_out)

for member in root.findall('nasl'):
    plugin = []

    id = member.find('script_id').text
    plugin.append(id)

    name = member.find('script_name').text
    plugin.append(name)

    family = member.find('script_family').text
    plugin.append(family)

    #for each in member.iterfind('nasl'):
    try:
        solution = member.xpath('.//name/text()')
        if solution == 'solution':
            plugin.append(solution)
    except AttributeError:
        solution = 'Unknown'
        plugin.append(solution)
    csvwriter.writerow(plugin)
nessus_out.close()
```

The ultimatate goals is to search for "solution" and get the corrensponding value from its  tag.

The xml structure is as follows:

```
nasl_plugins
nasl_plugins/nasl
nasl_plugins/nasl/filename
nasl_plugins/nasl/script_id
nasl_plugins/nasl/script_name
nasl_plugins/nasl/script_family
nasl_plugins/nasl/attributes/attribute/name
nasl_plugins/nasl/attributes/attribute/value
```

For Daniel:

Xml snippet:

```
<nasl>
<filename>fedora_2017-c3149b5fcb.nasl</filename>
<script_id>101028</script_id>
<script_name>Fedora 25 : xen (2017-c3149b5fcb)</script_name>
<script_version>$Revision: 1.5 $</script_version>
<script_copyright>This script is Copyright (C) 2017-2018 Tenable Network Security, Inc.</script_copyright>
<script_family>Fedora Local Security Checks</script_family>
<cves>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10911</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10912</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10913</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10915</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10916</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10917</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10918</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10919</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10920</cve>
 <cve>CVE-2017-10923</cve>
</cves>
<bids>
</bids>
<xrefs>
 <xref>FEDORA:2017-c3149b5fcb</xref>
 <xref>IAVB:2017-B-0074</xref>
</xrefs>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>ssh_get_info.nasl</dependency>
</dependencies>
<required_keys>
 <key>Host/local_checks_enabled</key>
 <key>Host/RedHat/release</key>
 <key>Host/RedHat/rpm-list</key>
</required_keys>
<attribute> 
  <name>plugin_type</name> 
  <value>local</value> 
</attribute> 
<attribute> 
  <name>plugin_modification_date</name> 
  <value>2018/02/02</value> 
</attribute> 
<attribute> 
  <name>stig_severity</name> 
  <value>I</value> 
</attribute> 
<attribute> 
  <name>cvss_base_score</name> 
  <value>10.0</value> 
</attribute> 
</attributes>
```

What im looking for is the values of stig_severity, base_cvss_score and som others aswell.. So my reasoning as to search for the  and they move down one line and get the value.. As for the csv, i need it in one line pr. plugin, so in this format:
`id,name,family,solution,description,synopsis,base_cvss_score,plugin_type,stig_severity` and then values for the next plugin on the next line..

Comment: I tried doing stuff with lxml once too - gave up on it and did it in Java instead. If you want more sophisticated xpath expressions - that's best way to go.

Comment: Java isnt really an option for me, did try it with bash, but It handles large files really badly, at least for my..

Comment: This seems like a really easy question that is hard to answer without sample XML. Can you please add a minimal example of the XML along with what you'd expect the CSV to look like? lxml has pretty good xpath support (1.0) so this should be very doable.

Comment: The entrie file is just plugins listed one after another with mostly the same tags, I need to loop through then, get the value of a give <name> and skip if its not present. Then export it all to the csv file. All the plugin tags start with the <nasl> tag, and all contain script_id/name/family, but the remainding tags(synopsis,plugin_type and so on) are not allways present in all plugins, so I need to be able to search for them but skip if not present..

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Good first question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of the values you want are direct children of `nasl` and some are in `attributes/attribute`.

What you *could* do is have two lists (or tuples); one with the exact element names and one with the exact attribute names (`attribute/name`).

Note: This might sound a little confusing because in this case "attribute name" is really an element named "attribute" with a child element named "name" and not a true XML attribute named "name".

Combining these tuples will give you all the fields in your CSV. You can use this to build a dict containing all of the fields with default values of `Unknown`.

Then you can iterate over both tuples to build your two different types of XPaths. If the element exists, the text value is updated in the dict. Otherwise the value remains `Unknown`.

Example...

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```xml
<nasl_plugins>
    <nasl>
        <filename>fedora_2017-c3149b5fcb.nasl</filename>
        <script_id>101028</script_id>
        <script_name>Fedora 25 : xen (2017-c3149b5fcb)</script_name>
        <script_version>$Revision: 1.5 $</script_version>
        <script_copyright>This script is Copyright (C) 2017-2018 Tenable Network Security,
            Inc.</script_copyright>
        <script_family>Fedora Local Security Checks</script_family>
        <cves>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10911</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10912</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10913</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10915</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10916</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10917</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10918</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10919</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10920</cve>
            <cve>CVE-2017-10923</cve>
        </cves>
        <bids> </bids>
        <xrefs>
            <xref>FEDORA:2017-c3149b5fcb</xref>
            <xref>IAVB:2017-B-0074</xref>
        </xrefs>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>ssh_get_info.nasl</dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <required_keys>
            <key>Host/local_checks_enabled</key>
            <key>Host/RedHat/release</key>
            <key>Host/RedHat/rpm-list</key>
        </required_keys>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>plugin_type</name>
                <value>local</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>plugin_modification_date</name>
                <value>2018/02/02</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>stig_severity</name>
                <value>I</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>cvss_base_score</name>
                <value>10.0</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </nasl>
</nasl_plugins>
```

**Python 3.x**

```
import csv
from lxml import etree

elem_names = ('script_id', 'script_name', 'script_family')
attr_names = ('solution', 'description', 'synopsis', 'cvss_base_score', 'plugin_type',
              'stig_severity')
field_names = elem_names + attr_names

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as xml_data_to_csv:

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(xml_data_to_csv, fieldnames=field_names, 
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    csv_writer.writeheader()

    tree = etree.parse('test.xml')

    for nasl in tree.xpath('.//nasl'):
        # Build a dict containing all of the "field_names" with default values of "Unknown".
        values = {key: 'Unknown' for key in field_names}

        # Process the direct children of "nasl".
        for elem_name in elem_names:
            for child in nasl.xpath(f'*[self::{elem_name}]'):
                values[child.tag] = child.text

        # Process attribute with matching attribute names.
        for attr_name in attr_names:
            for val in nasl.xpath(f'attributes/attribute[name="{attr_name}"]/value'):
                values[attr_name] = val.text

        csv_writer.writerow(values)
```

**Output** (test.csv)

```
"script_id","script_name","script_family","solution","description","synopsis","cvss_base_score","plugin_type","stig_severity"
"101028","Fedora 25 : xen (2017-c3149b5fcb)","Fedora Local Security Checks","Unknown","Unknown","Unknown","10.0","local","I"
```

Comment: Daniel you are an absolute champ.. thank you very very much.. I can see that my own understanding of lxml would not have been enough.